# How do I monitor which applications are running?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am completely new to python, and just wanted to make a simple console program for my personal use. It is a console countdown timer that will activate a sound when I am on a certain app or a website. I made the timer and I know how to make it play the sound, but I can't get it to detect which apps and websites I am on and to do it only when the timer is running.

This is what I have for the timer:

```
# import the time module
import time
from playsound import playsound


# define the countdown func.
def countdown(t):
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1

    print('You`re done!')


# input time in seconds
t = input("Enter the time in seconds: ")

# function call
countdown(int(t))
```

Comment: Depending on your OS, you may need something like [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to scan the titles of your apps to see what's running

Comment: Knowing if a process is running is not too hard, but being able to recognise if that process is the one the user is currently interacting with, or delving into a browser to know which websites are being accessed, is lot harder. You need to narrow the scope of your question, at the moment it is too broad to be answered here.